# How to add \n as text in a String while doing Java programming in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, string

When I add `\n` in any String in Android Studio while programming in `Java` ,
`\n` is treated as a ***new line character*** in `TextView`.

How do I add `\n` as a text in a String ? I don't want it to be treated as a *newline* character in `TextView`.

Comment: You tried  "\\n"?

Comment: Escape the the escape character `\\\` :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to escape the the escape character \n then see below example:

Use like this

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Here is \\n my toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Here is \n my toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```